# Run-time Equivalent to Assign Local Data... for TClientDataSet and TSQLQuery

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, tdbgrid

The *TSQLQuery* class is unidirectional, so for it to be used as a source for a data-bound *TDBGrid*, a *TClientDataSet* needs to be linked between the *TSQLQuery* and the *TDataSource* that the *TDBGrid* is bound to.

I can connect the *TSQLConnection* and make the *TSQLQuery* active at design-time, with specified params, and then I can right-click on the CDS and choose the "Assign Local Data..." option to have it grab the data from the *TSQLQuery*, which then appears in the *TDBGrid* via the linked *TDataSource*.

The amount of time between choosing "Assign Local Data..." and the data actually appearing in the grid is very short, so I am looking for the way to replicate this at run-time.

Supposedly, I can set the **Data** property of the CDS to the **Data** of the source, but a *TSQLQuery* has no Data property. There was a post about using a provider, but

```
DataSetProvider1.DataSet := SQLQuery1;
ClientDataSet1.Data := DataSetProvider1.Data;
```

throws an access violation,

I did implement the data copy by looping through the *TSQLQuery* and appending the records to the *TClientDataSet*, but that was a lot slower than the "Assign Local Data...".

[Edit 1]

All the components I need are hooked up at design-time, and I can make the *TSQLConnection* active, then the *TSQLQuery*, then the *TClientDataSet* and the *TDBGrid* displays the data from the parameterised query defined in the *TSQLQuery*.

In the **OnChange** event of a *TComboBox*, I need to refresh the query using a different parameter and have the grid show the relevant results, so I **Close** the *TSQLQuery*, change the **ParamByName** value, **Open** the *TSQLQuery* and then call **ClientDataSet1.Last** to highlight the last row in the grid.

That gives me a "Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset" error, so I use

```
ClientDataSet1.Active := true;
```

but that throws an "Access Violation".

All the examples I can find are all about dropping components onto a form, linking them together, and they work. Well, yes they do, but I need to change properties in code at run-time and still have it work, which it just refuses to do.

This is really beginning to frustrate me.

[Edit 2]

So I followed the example on the Embarcadero site for building a VCL Forms dbExpress Database Application, substituting my database connection details for the Interbase one the example uses.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Building_a_VCL_Forms_dbExpress_Database_Application

In the designer, everything looked fine and the grid was showing the results from the query, but when I went to run it using F9, I was getting an "Access Violation" thrown from within *TCustomClientDataSet.InternalCheck*.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out this is a known **MIDAS.DLL** versioning problem and can be resolved by including **MIDASLib** in the uses clause of the form. It is just unfortunate that the *Datasnap.DBClient* code is still throwing Access Violations instead of proper messages, especially since this problem was reported in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. Just change TUniConnection and TUniQuery to what You are using:

```
Procedure CdsAssignTable(aTableName:String; aCds : TClientDataSet; aCon 
:TUniConnection );
Var
   aQUery : TUniQuery;
aProvider : TDataSetProvider;

begin
if aCon=Nil then raise Exception.Create('aCon=Nil');
if aCds=Nil then aCds:=TClientDataSet.Create(aCon.Owner);


 aQUery:=TUniQuery.Create(Nil);
 aQUery.SQL.Text:='select * from '+aTableName;
 aQUery.Connection:=aCon;
 aQUery.Open;
 aProvider:=TDataSetProvider.Create(Nil);
 aProvider.DataSet:=aQUery;
 aCds.Data:=aProvider.Data;
 FreeAndNil(aProvider);
 FreeAndNil(aQUery);
End;
```

Comment: This code is the same as the OP wrote in the question itself, where the OP also explains why it did not work for the components they are using. You should read the question again more carefully; see particularly the very first code snippet they provided.